# What this error means on Google Earth Engine console? "Image (Error) Invalid JSON"

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

When I run my code on GEE I receive the following error in the line `print(unitScale)`.

`Image (Error) Invalid JSON`.

```js
var features = (elevation
    .addBands(slope)
    .addBands(curve)
    .addBands(landcover) // Can disaggregate to dummy features in Python
    .addBands(twi)
    .addBands(spi)
    .addBands(sti)
    .addBands(mtpi)
    .addBands(lith)
    .addBands(GSWPerm)
    .addBands(GSWDistSeasonal)
    .addBands(aspect)
    .addBands(hand)
    .clip(region))
// .clip(elevation.geometry()));

features = features.reproject({
    crs: aspect.projection().crs(),
    scale: 30
}).float()

var minMax = features.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 40e9,
    bestEffort: true
})

// use unit scale to normalize the pixel values

var unitScale = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
    features.bandNames().map(function (name) {
        name = ee.String(name);

        var band = features.select(name);

        return band.unitScale(ee.Number(minMax.get(name.cat('_min'))), ee.Number(minMax.get(name.cat('_max'))))
    })).toBands().rename(features.bandNames());

print(unitScale) /// I receive the error in this line ///

print(features)
```

Comment: The error message "Invalid JSON" suggests that there is a problem with the format of the output that the code is trying to print, which is likely caused by the unitScale variable.

One possible reason for the error is that unitScale may have a large size, and printing it as an ee.Image can cause memory issues. Try adding .limit(10) before .toBands() to limit the number of images in the collection to 10, which can reduce the size of the unitScale image and resolve the error